# Why I can only send 3 row via netcat on UDP port?

Tags: udp, netcat

I am new to this command I am sending a file data on UDP 9415 port . 
--> I have file which has 1000 rows 
--> I am firing here IP is my destination IP

```
cat test1 | netcat -u 172.x.x.x 9514
```

--> Now on destination i have syslog-ng which recieves data and store it in a folder and after step 2 I am only getting first 3 records of the file .

Does this means UDP has some limit . So I have kill the command in second step and rerun the command then again I recieve 3 records and so on .

Can someone suggest what could be an issue ?

Regards
VG

Comment: Why are you using UDP?  You know UDP is connection-less right?  So depending on the protocol that may mean everything you are sending must fit in a single datagram(packet)?

Comment: Also, i with UDP it is not guaranteed that the packets arrive in the same order you send them. Or that they arrive at all.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the haters in the comments, UDP is awesome for certain things - such as high performance logging.

I would look at the receive buffer size - if you send a datagram larger than the buffer, it will truncate the datagram.

> When receiving messages using the UDP protocol, increase the size of the UDP receive buffer on the receiver host (that is, the syslog-ng OSE server or relay receiving the messages). Note that on certain platforms, for example, on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, even low message load (~200 messages per second) can result in message loss, unless the so_rcvbuf() option of the source is increased. In such cases, you will need to increase the net.core.rmem_max parameter of the host (for example, to 1024000), but do not modify net.core.rmem_default parameter.
>
> As a general rule, increase the so_rcvbuf() so that the buffer size in kilobytes is higher than the rate of incoming messages per second. For example, to receive 2000 messages per second, set the so_rcvbuf() at least to 2 097 152 bytes.

(source: https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.3-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.3-guide-admin-en/html/reference_source_tcpudp.html)

I also haven't used `nc` for UDP specifically, so I'm not sure if it does any modification of the data. You could use `tcpdump -xvv dst port 9514` to validate what the UDP datagrams actually are being sent as. Typically, I just pipe directly to: `tail -f -n0 /var/log/nodejs/log.log > /dev/udp/serverhostnamehere/9996`

Comment: Thanks Smith, I like the way you elaborate the answer thanks for that . So any idea how I can increase the buffer size on Ubuntu . I mean is there any direct command or any file where I can modify the settings .

Comment: Could do something like: `input(type="imudp" port="9514" rcvbufSize="256M")` for rsyslog